# R Streamline Large Dataset with Nested If Statements

Tags: r, conditional-statements

I'm transcribing a SAS script into R and was wondering if there's a more streamlined way of running through the multiple conditional statements

I have a dataframe with almost 900,000 rows and 44 columns, so a for loop is taking forever.  Below is a subset of my data with a version of my script I will be using.  One major issue I'm running into is how to execute lines 7-10 within an if statement to create values and then use those values down the hierarchy.

```
dt <- data.frame(v1 = c(0.0449, 0.0462, 0.1899, 0.2074, 0.1778), 
              v2 = c(0.8637, 0.9417, 0.4258, 0.7083, 0.6962), 
              v3 = c(0,0, 0.2501, 0.0474, 0.126))

for(i in seq_len(nrow(dt))){
  if(sum(dt$v1[i],dt$v2[i],dt$v3[i], na.rm = T) >= 0.5){
    dt$scale[i] = 1/sum(dt$v1[i],dt$v2[i],dt$v3[i], na.rm = T)
    dt$v1_scale[i] <- dt$v1[i] * dt$scale[i]
    dt$v2_scale[i] <- dt$v2[i] * dt$scale[i]
    dt$v3_scale[i] <- dt$v3[i] * dt$scale[i]

    if(dt$v1_scale[i] >= 0.75){
      dt$cat[i] <- "D"
    } else if(dt$v2_scale[i] >= 0.9){
      dt$cat[i] <- "F2"
    }else if(dt$v2_scale[i] >= 0.75){
      dt$cat[i] <- "F1"
    } else if(dt$v3_scale[i] >= 0.75){
      dt$cat[i] <- "A"
    } else if(dt$v3_scale[i] >= max(dt$v1_scale[i], dt$v2_scale[i], na.rm = T)){
      if(dt$v1_scale[i] >= dt$v2_scale[i]){
        dt$cat[i] <- "B"
      } else{
        dt$cat[i] <- "C"
      }
    } else if(dt$v1_scale[i] >= max(dt$v3_scale[i], dt$v2_scale[i], na.rm = T)){
      if(dt$v3_scale[i] >= dt$v2_scale[i]){
        dt$cat[i] <- "B"
      } else{
        dt$cat[i] <- "E"
      }
    } else if(dt$v3_scale[i] >= dt$v1_scale[i]){
      dt$cat[i] <- "C"
    } else{
      dt$cat[i] <- "E"
    }
  }
}
```

I've recently been trying to learn more about the data.table API, so I would be interested to hear if it's possible with data.table API.  Honestly, anything to make this faster would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: Check out dplyr's `case_when()` function for general vectorized if-else statements https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dplyr/versions/0.7.8/topics/case_when

Comment: @FilipW thank you and that did speed it up with some modifications, but my issue is the first condition is kind of a master condition that all the others fall into. Also, if the first condition is true I need to create multiple columns to be used on another nested if statement when true. I'm not sure if it's possible to do that with if_else or case_when, so I might have to just modify or subset my dataframe. 
Also, can you have another if statement when an if statement is true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a vectorized solution that is much faster (~40x) than your initial `for` loop. The major difference is I took out your initial `if` condition because that seemed useless. Even if there are some cases when the conditions does not holds true, those cases can be removed later in a vectorized way. This reduces computational burden. I have also included a benchmark test for comparison. Test it and see if you get any computational benefit.

```
dt=data.frame(v1 = c(0.0449, 0.0462, 0.1899, 0.2074, 0.1778), 
              v2 = c(0.8637, 0.9417, 0.4258, 0.7083, 0.6962), 
              v3 = c(0,0, 0.2501, 0.0474, 0.126))
dt.sum <- rowSums(dt)
scale <- 1/dt.sum
v1_scale <- scale * dt$v1
v2_scale <- scale * dt$v2
v3_scale <- scale * dt$v3
cat <- rep("E", nrow(dt))

cat <- sapply(seq_along(cat), function(i) {
  if(v1_scale[i] >= 0.75) {
    "D"
  } else if(v2_scale[i] >= 0.9){
    "F2"
  } else if(v2_scale[i] >= 0.75){
    "F1"
  } else if(v3_scale[i] >= 0.75){
    "A"
  } else if(v3_scale[i] >= max(v1_scale[i], v2_scale[i], na.rm = T)){
    if(v1_scale[i] >= v2_scale[i]){
      "B"
    } else {
      "C"
    }
  } else if(v1_scale[i] >= max(v3_scale[i], v2_scale[i], na.rm = T)){
    if(v3_scale[i] >= v2_scale[i]){
      "B"
    }
  } else if(v3_scale[i] >= v1_scale[i]){
    "C"
  } else {
    "E"
  }
}
)

dt <- data.frame(dt, scale, v1_scale, v2_scale, v3_scale, cat, stringsAsFactors = F)
```

**Microbenchmark**

```
Unit: microseconds
     expr       min         lq       mean     median         uq      max neval
 original 33401.067 36136.9285 38588.6041 38226.7850 39607.3545 95425.23   100
 modified   688.127   762.4395   962.0771   847.9485   901.8755 12690.76   100
```

Comment: Thank you!  I knew there had to be some way to do it within the apply family, but I've never used sapply as the i of the iteration.